# threejs - dynamically adding shadow light for large scene

Tags: three.js

I'm facing issues to show shadows consistently for the 3D objects in the large scene.

In my case, objects would be added dynamically to the scene and the scene may grow larger and larger. When I have a single `DirectionalLight` for casting shadow it becomes blur. So I fixed an optimal settings for the `DirectionalLight` and thought to dynamically add more sources as and when it is required, so that shadow shows up consistently. Not sure if this is the correct approach, please correct me if I'm wrong.

So, I was experimenting to add a `DirectionalLight` to top, bottom, left and right of the current `DirectionalLight` source. I was able to add the `DirectionalLight`, however, intensity of the shadow become lighter as I add each `DirectionalLight` and after adding on the third side, shadow becomes invisible. Confused on how to proceed.

https://jsfiddle.net/arundhaj/6zL5tobk/

In the above experiment, you can find, I am getting consistent shadow with only two sources.

```
addShadowToBottom(shadowCameraPosition);
// addShadowToTop(shadowCameraPosition);
// addShadowToLeft(shadowCameraPosition);
// addShadowToRight(shadowCameraPosition);
```

shadow effect changes when uncommenting light on each side.

```
const shadowLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
```

If I change the intensity of light from `1` to `0.5`, shadow shows up, however, it is very light and not as dark and crisp as it was at `1`.

Is there any other approach to work on my scenario? Please let me know.